# Match strings which are similar but diffetent in writing style

Tags: python, nlp, pattern-matching

I want to know is there any easy way to match strings like,
i.e MBA with master in buisness administration, M.B.A, M-B-A, mba
    or Ms in Cs with masters in computer science, or with M.s in Computer science, MS in (computer science), etc 
These strings are similar from each other but differet writing styles 
I am working on some CV project where i have to match Job post education with eduction written in candidates CV, therefore it could be the case where some education written in jop post in some way and same thing exists in cv with another format like in jop post it found MBA and in cv it founds master in buisness administration how should i deal with it ?.......thankx in advance

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! If you already haven't, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried until this point ?

Comment: i have tried this technique, i save all the writing styles in db like key value pairs like MBA is key and its other formats will be values when some education is get from job post it seach in all tuples where found it gets its Id same thing do when educ extracted from cv if found get its id if id's are same means that they are similar strings.

Comment: but i want to know if there is other ways also which i could use or you could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

String patterns can usually be found using regex (in python the 're' package), without an example of your code and data structure there's not much I can do, but grouping strings such as MBA, M.B.A or M-B-A can easily be done using regex

Comment: rotern tall i have used regex to extract data from CV's but it is matching now  iave to do matching for i.e from CV i extracted from regex M.B.A but from jop post i found mba from using regex now M.B.A=mba which have to be matched

Comment: If you could add a code snippet to describe your problem better, it would be helpful